# calulating sample excess kurtosis using R package fBasics

Tags: r, statistics

I used fBasics package to calculate the sample excess kurtosis of a very simple vector [1,2,3]:

```
> library(fBasics)
> x=c(1,2,3)
> kurtosis(x)
[1] -2.333333
attr(,"method")
[1] "excess"
```

What I calculated based on WIkipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Sample_kurtosis, is -1.5. So I wonder why the fBaswics package gives a different result?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a `kurtosis` function in that package. Can you double check please?

Comment: I intall it from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fBasics/index.html

Comment: There is no (exported) function by that name in that package. As I suspected, the `kurtosis` function you end up using is one from another package that **fBasics** imports. It's from the **timeDate** package, apparently. It says this when you look at `?kurtosis`.

Comment: Actually `kurtosis` is in timeDate which is automatically loaded when running `library(fBasics)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `kurtosis` from moments package instead.

```
> library(moments)
> kurtosis(x)
[1] 1.5
```

`kurtosis` from momments computes the estimator of Pearson's measure of kurtosis. This function is implemented (if `x` is a numeric vector) as follows:

```
n <- length(x)
n * sum((x - mean(x))^4)/(sum((x - mean(x))^2)^2)
```

For you to get the excess of kurtosis use:

```
> kurtosis(x)-3
[1] -1.5
```

Now, for you to understand what's different in `kurtosis` form fBasics, look at the code, for that use:

```
library(fBasics)
methods("kurtosis")
getAnywhere("kurtosis.default")
```

and if `x` is a numeric vector, then the excess of kurtosis is defined in kurtosis from fBasics (actually from timeDate, see my comment) as:

```
sum((x - mean(x))^4/as.numeric(var(x))^2)/length(x) - 3
```

I think this will help you. The question in your comment is looking for a basic statistical answer, I've just pointed out the R programming hints for you to get the answer for your homework.

Comment: My textbook asks me to use fBasics. Can you help me if the kurtosis function in fbasics is wrong? I would like to calculate sample excess kurtosis, and not sure if the estimator of Pearson's measure of kurtosis is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. so is the function kurtosis() in timeDate wrong?

Comment: Hi Jilber, I posted a question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84050/definition-of-sample-excess-kurtosis.